# how to change URL format using UrlRewrite and htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i am currently using

```
http://server.com/index.php?page1=main&page2=contacts
```

i want to change it like

```
http://server.com/main/contacts
```

can you help how to write .htaccess file with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^main/contacts$ index.php?page1=main&page2=contacts [L]
```

OR (for dynamic pages)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?page1=$1&page2=$2
```